# Redis Cluster Configuration

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

I am using spring `redisTemplate(jedis, 2.0.0)` with `redis-server(2.9.50)`. It's working perfectly for the single instance but I want to create a cluster master-slave environment with two different instances in which replication and failover happen automatically (over configuration).

Please answer the following queries

what's the proper way to create master/slave Redis cluster(right now I've only `redis-server` installed with no config change)?

how to connect `jedis` with `redis` cluster ?

**what should I use to replicate data between redis clusters nodes ?**

Comment: you may want to split this question up into multiple questions, its very broad right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to upgrade your version of jedis to get the cluster support. From the [README](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/README.md), the usage looks straight-forward:

```
Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
//Jedis Cluster will attempt to discover cluster nodes automatically
jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 7379));
JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
jc.set("foo", "bar");
String value = jc.get("foo");
```

In terms of setup, there's a lot of considerations, you should consult this [tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) for basic setup and considerations. The section **Creating a Redis Cluster using the create-cluster script** will get you up and running pretty quickly and you can make tweaks & changes from there.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers leeor, I am able to create cluster with the provided code and tutorials.

Comment: awesome, glad to help.